# margin-right is not showing

Tags: html, css

Below is my CSS and HTML code. As you can see the margin on right is not coming.

1. Can anybody tell me the reason for this?
2. Is the structure of HTML, CSS right? I have to show two windows in the middle of the page and a footer and a header. So, I have positioned everything absolute.

Is that correct practice?

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    min-height: 100vh;
    min-width: 100vh;
}

.wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    bottom: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    right: 0%;
    background-color: #666;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.header{
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    top: 0%;
    height: 10%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.footer{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0%;
    height: 10%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

.header .brand-header{

}

.window{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 10%;
    bottom: 10%;
    background-color: #eee;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Layout</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header"> </div>

    <div class="window">
        <div class="sub-window left-window"> </div>
        <div class="sub-window right-window"> </div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer"> </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would be helpful in this case to include a Fiddle.

Comment: Be careful with position, be very careful.

Comment: @Utkanos why? The snippet should alwasy be preferred since all the code remains here.

Comment: I never said *instead of* putting the code in the question. Sometimes it's nice to see what people are aiming for, as it can be hard to visualise.

Comment: Absolute positioning for page layouting in general is rather a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply width `calc` like

```
.window {
    background-color: #eee;
    bottom: 10%;
    margin: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    width: calc(100% - 20px); /*You apply margin:10px;*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

that is just because your width is 100% and you applied an margin of 20 px(margin-left:10,margin-right:10) => in effect it requires space of 100% + 20px. that is the reason for you can trace out margin on your right side.

use **`width: calc(100% - 20px);`** on your .window ,it will works fine.

```css
*{
 margin:0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
 min-height: 100vh;
 min-width: 100vh;
}

.wrapper{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0%;
 bottom: 0%;
 left: 0%;
 right: 0%;
 background-color: #666;
 overflow-x: hidden;
  
}

.header{
 position: absolute;
 margin: 0;
    top: 0%;
    height: 10%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.footer{
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0%;
 height: 10%;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

.header .brand-header{

}

.window{
 position: absolute;
 width: calc(100% - 20px);
 top: 10%;
 bottom: 10%;
 background-color: #eee;
 margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Layout</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="header">
 </div>

 <div class="window">
  <div class="sub-window left-window">
   
  </div>
  <div class="sub-window right-window">
   
  </div>

 </div>

 <div class="footer">
  
 </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```